# @Url.Action does not pass parameters to the action method on submit

Tags: url.action

I have seen various posts for this problem and i have tried almost whatever solution I could find but nothing seems to work.
I need to pass parameter in the url from view to Controller. the url should look somethinkg like this:
https://localhost:44300/Name/GetName?name=Zeeba 
In my View i have a text field and I enter a value in the text field, which i am trying to pass to Controller. My View is like this:

```
<div>
@Html.LabelFor(Name)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.name)
</div>
<div>
<p><a class="btn btn-default" href="@Url.Action("GetName", "Name", new { name= Model.name})">Get Name</a>                     
</p>
</div>
```

My Controller is something like this:

```
public ActionResult GetName( string name)
 {
     string newName= Request.QueryString["name"];    
  }
```

When I enter the name in the textBox and click on the button the value of name in Controller is NULL. 
Whereas if I add a hardcoded value for name the value is correctly passed to the Controller something like this:

```
<p><a class="btn btn-default" href="@Url.Action("GetName", "Name", new { name= "Zeeba" })">Get Name</a></p>
```

Why does it behave like this? Could someone please help.